# Turn python script into a function

Tags: python, python-module

Assume I wrote a script `morning.py` which does a simple print statement

```
# morning.py
print 'Good morning'
```

Some hours later I've realized that I have to use this script in another script named `evening.py`. I am aware of two options. First, to invoke `morning.py` as a subprocess

```
# evening.py
import subprocess
import shlex
process = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split('python morning.py'))
process.communicate()
```

This is the way I've initially chosen. The problem is that I want to pack my program (`morning` + `evening`) into a single executable. And to my understanding, from the exe file such call just won't work.

Another option is to turn module `morning` into a function. For instance, like that

```
# morning.py
def morning_func():
   print 'Good morning'
```

Then I can simply call this function from the `evening` module

```
# evening
import morning
morning.morning_func()
```

Here the problem is that unlike `morning` my actual initial script is quite extended and messy. There is no single function that I can execute to simulate script running flow. Wrapping the whole script in a function just does not feel right.

What are possible solutions?

Comment: There's absolutely *no* good reason to run a Python script from another via Popen. Why can't you just import it as is?

Comment: Refactor `morning` so that it has a main function.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Assume in `evening` script I added a line `import morning`. How do I get the `'Good morning'` greeting from inside `evening`?

Comment: @DanielRoseman On import of `morning` the message prints automatically. I didn't realize that the modules are run when imported. Feeling dumb.

Comment: @WeatherReport: beware, module are run when **first** imported. The following script : `print 'First'; import morning ; print "Second" ; import morning` will only print `Good morning` once. Unsure whether is the expected result...

Answer (score 7):

The common usage is to always declare functions (and/or classes) in a module that can be used by other modules and to add at the end a `if __name__ == '__main__':` test to directly exec something if the script is called directly.

In your example, it would give:

```
# morning.py
def morning_func():
   print 'Good morning'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # call morning func
    morning_func()
```

That way, you can execute it simply as `python morning.py` or include it in other Python files to call `morning_func` from there

Comment: This does not directly address my question but might be useful for others.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to above answer, the best way in this case would be to go through the original morning script line by line and wrap the actions in related functions. Refer this recipe on [How to convert a Python script to module](https://tutswiki.com/convert-python-script-to-module/).

Answer (score 0):

As you said calling morning like that is messy, I Suggest import morning like this:

```
# main.py
from morning import morning_func as morning
```

then you can call morning like this:

```
morning()
```

If you wanna run `morning.py` separately, as @Serge Ballesta said modify `morning.py` like this:

```
# morning.py
def morning_func():
   print 'Good morning'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    morning_func()
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a directory `my_script` and then create a `__init__.py` file in that directory? You can then put your entire script inside the `__init__.py` file.

To run the script from your python program, you can

```
import my_script
my_script
```